# how to transform json into dataframe as in a specific format in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

while hitting an API I got JSON response which is as below

```
res_data_dict= {
      "states": [
        {
          "state_code": "U.P",
          "state_name": "UTTAR PRADESH"
        },
        {
          "state_code": "U.K",
          "state_name": "UTTARAKHAND"
        }
      ]
    }
```

and while transforming it to dataframe

```
v=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res_data_dict)
```

I got output as follows

[image]

but my expected output dataframe should be

[image]

Comment: Because json has only one key and that is `states` and value of `states` is and array with two elements.

Comment: Why do you expect to have u.k in the column with the name state_code while it is under index_code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`pd.Dataframe constructor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with [`df.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
In [698]: df = pd.DataFrame(res_data_dict['states'])

In [700]: df.state_name = df.state_name.combine_first(df.index_name)

In [701]: df.state_code = df.state_code.combine_first(df.index_code)

In [703]: df.drop(['index_code', 'index_name'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [704]: df
Out[704]: 
  state_code     state_name
0        U.P  UTTAR PRADESH
1        U.K    UTTARAKHAND
```

Comment: @aniltiwari Please let me know if the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'State_{}'.format(k.split('_')[1]):v for k,v in dicts.items()} for dicts in res_data_dict['states']])

>>> print(df)
  State_code     State_name
0        U.P  UTTAR PRADESH
1        U.K    UTTARAKHAND
```